# Build up and array with variable property name

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML looks like this:

```
<label data-plural="foos" data-id="1">Foo</label>
<label data-plural="bars" data-id="2">Bar</label>
```

I have this code:

```
var commands = new Array();

$('label.ptype').each(function(k,v) {
    var category = $(v).data('plural');
    var cmd = 'show ' + category;
    var id = $(v).data('id');
    commands.push({cmd : function() { window.alert(id + " " + category); exploreId(id, category); }});
});

console.log(commands);
```

I would like to have in the commands array:

```
[   
 { 'show foos': function() { window.alert('1 foos'); exploreId(1, 'foos'); },
 { 'show bars': function() { window.alert('2 bars'); exploreId(2, 'bars'); }
]
```

But what I am getting is literally

```
[ { cmd: function() ... }, { cmd: function() ... } ]
```

So what is a good way to build the desired array?

Comment: because cmd is a literal key name - you may be able to use computed names ...`commands.push({ ['show ' + category]: function ...` depending on your browser

Answer (score 1):

In ES5, you have to take apart the object construction:

```
var command = {};
command[cmd] = function() { window.alert(id + " " + category); exploreId(id, category); };
commands.push(command);
```

In ES2015, you can use `[ ]` notation in the object initializer:

```
commands.push({ [cmd] : function() { window.alert(id + " " + category); exploreId(id, category); }});
```

That new feature ("computed property names") is supported by Firefox and Chrome and Safari, but not Internet Explorer. (It may be in Edge but I can't find anything explicit and I'm too lazy to fire up my VM :)

Comment: Ok I'll start the VM.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, readability and execution speed, use the `[]` instead of `new Array();`.

You can use a `temporary object`, an push it into commands (`Works on Chrome, Firefox and IE`):

```js
var commands = [];
$('label').each(function(k,v) {
    var category = $(v).data('plural');
    var id = $(v).data('id');
    var temp = {};
    temp['show ' + category] = function() { window.alert(id + " " + category); exploreId(id, category); };
    commands.push(temp);
});
console.log(commands);
console.log(commands[0]['show foos']());//run function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label data-plural="foos" data-id="1">Foo</label>
<label data-plural="bars" data-id="2">Bar</label>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/h0ekmreu/

Comment: you probably should mention that this only works in firefox and chrome, not internet explorer (edge status unknown to me)

Comment: Updated answer for ie